# Invalid layers for facet_grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been working with a variation on this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

Compare = matrix(c(
0,           0,           "Soil 1", "tF",
0.379268025, 5.555806214, "Soil 1", "tF",
0.961561989, 13.05580621, "Soil 1", "tF",
1.55418685,  20.55580621, "Soil 1", "tF",
0,           0,           "Soil 2", "tF",
0.104297312, 1.581249799, "Soil 2", "tF",
0.705818262, 6.081249799, "Soil 2", "tF",
1.447379092, 10.5812498,  "Soil 2", "tF",
0,           20,          "Soil 1", "tf",
0.379268025, 13.1603086,  "Soil 1", "tf",
0.961561989, 12.72354396, "Soil 1", "tf",
1.55418685,  12.60549558, "Soil 1", "tf",
0,           20,          "Soil 2", "tf",
0.104297312, 10.51383279, "Soil 2", "tf",
0.705818262, 6.433709727, "Soil 2", "tf",
1.447379092, 5.82398083,  "Soil 2", "tf",
0,           0,           "Soil 1", "zf",
0.379268025, 205.7706005, "Soil 1", "zf",
0.961561989, 483.5483783, "Soil 1", "zf",
1.55418685,  761.3261561, "Soil 1", "zf",
0,           0,           "Soil 2", "zf",
0.104297312, 23.25367352, "Soil 2", "zf",
0.705818262, 89.43014411, "Soil 2", "zf",
1.447379092, 155.6066147, "Soil 2", "zf"), nrow = 24, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

plot = ggplot(as.data.frame(Compare),
aes(as.double(Compare[,1]), as.double(Compare[,2]), color = Compare[,3])) +
    geom_point() + facet_grid(Compare[,4] ~ .)
plot
```

My issue is with the `facet_grid()` aspect of the code.  If I comment it out or delete it, it runs great, so I know I can isolate my issue to something that has to do with it.  What I'm trying to accomplish is a set of three panels stacked vertically, with `Compare[,1]` on the x-axis, `Compare[,2]` on the y-axis, coloration based on `Compare[,3]` (producing a set of points for both soil types on each facet), and the three facets produced according to `Compare[,4]`.

The error I get when I run with `facet_grid()` included in the code is:

```
Error in layout_base(data, rows, drop = drop) : 
    At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

I feel like my error may be related to the forcing of doubles and dataframes to deal with the initial form of a matrix, but am not sure what needs to be changed.

Comment: you will be much better off if you name the columns of your data frame and refer to them by name.

Comment: @BenBolker, I actually do have them named in my full version of the code, but elected to remove the names in an attempt to produce the shortest reproducible code I could.  In the future, I'll be sure to follow this convention when posting; is it worth editing, or do I keep it the same as a warning to future newbies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issues are more far-reaching than just the `facet_grid` component.

1. Matrices can only hold a single type of data. If you have multiple types, use a `data.frame`.
2. You `as.double` code is not correct for coercing from `factor` to `numeric` (as required because you had a character matrix coerced --> data.frame.
3. `ggplot` and `aes` should refer to the column names, not the direct subsets of the data object using `[`.
4. `facet_grid` is even more particular required `names`, not even functions thereof.

So, to rescue your data.

```
CP <- as.data.frame(Compare)

CP[[1]] <- as.numeric(as.character(CP[[1]]))
CP[[2]] <- as.numeric(as.character(CP[[2]]))
# your data.frame names are..
names(CP)
# [1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4"

ggplot(CP, aes(x = V1, y = V2, colour = V3)) +
 geom_point() + facet_grid(V4 ~ . )
```

[image]

Comment: your fix produces the three panels, just as you indicated (awesome).  However, it looks like all of the rows in `CP` have picked up a constant value of (0, 0.379268).

Comment: @renegade8191 - My typo referenced the original matrix `Compare` not data.frame `CP` in the factor->numeric conversion. Fixed now.