# Error creating facets in ggplot2-based plotting function

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2

So I am trying to develop a`ggplot2`based plotting function for an existing R package. Users should be able to specify a data frame (datfile), a value for where a vertical line is placed in the plot (alpha), and a grouping variable (group) for creating subplots via faceting.

Here is some example data:

```
#Some hypothetical data
Computed=c(0.03, 0.25, 0.74, 0.02, 0.0023, 0.43, 0.56, 0.32, 0.005, 0.0032, 0.06)
Reported.P.Value=c(0.25, 0.24, 0.74, 0.01, 0.001, 0.40, 0.56, 0.32, 0.003, 0.0032, 0.02)
Journal=c("a", "b","a", "b","a", "b","a", "b","a", "b","a")

dat=data.frame(Computed, Reported.P.Value, Journal)
```

The function looks like this:

```
plot1 <- function(datfile, alpha, group){

p <- ggplot(datfile, aes(y = Computed,x = Reported.P.Value))   

p + geom_point(size=2.5)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=alpha, color="grey60",linetype="dashed")+
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, color="grey60")+
  annotate("text", x= 0.5, y = .10, label="overestimated")+
  annotate("text", x= 0.5, y = .90, label="underestimated")+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Reported p-values", breaks=c(0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Computed p-values", breaks=c(0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0))+
  facet_grid(group ~ .)
 }
```

If I ignore the function, and just execute the plotting code myself (substituting in the appropriate vectors from the data frame), everything works out fine: [image]

But if try to run the function the plotting function itself...:

```
plot1(dat, 0.05, Journal)
```

I get this error message:
`Error in layout_base(data, rows, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for faceting`

My error seems related to the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917289/invalid-layers-for-facet-grid-in-ggplot2), where the author of the accepted answer wrote:

> facet_grid is even more particular required names, not even functions thereof.

Does this mean that it's not possible for me to pass variables in a data frame to the faceting option within the function? My programming background is not fantastic, and it would be a real bummer if users of my function couldn't specify a faceting variable. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two changes from your original code: pass the facetting statement to `facet_grid` using `paste` to construct the appropriate string (per @aosmith's comment, a formula wrapper is not necessary), then pass the facet variable to the function as a string.

```
plot1 <- function(datfile, alpha, group){

  p <- ggplot(datfile, aes(y = Computed,x = Reported.P.Value))   

  p + geom_point(size=2.5)+
    geom_vline(xintercept=alpha, color="grey60",linetype="dashed")+
    geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, color="grey60")+
    annotate("text", x= 0.5, y = .10, label="overestimated")+
    annotate("text", x= 0.5, y = .90, label="underestimated")+
    scale_x_continuous(name="Reported p-values", breaks=c(0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0))+
    scale_y_continuous(name="Computed p-values", breaks=c(0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0))+
    facet_grid(paste(group, "~ ."))
}

plot1(dat, 0.5, "Journal")
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem?

Comment: @Soheil, `facet_grid` is expecting a formula, so we need to build the formula programmatically if we want the function to be flexible. To pass the correct column to the formula, we need a string, because `Journal` is not an independent object in the default environment. So instead we pass it as a string that goes into the formula and ggplot then knows to look for that column in the data frame that was fed to the function. I'm not sure if that's the most elegant way to do it, but it works.

Comment: The `facet_grid` function can take a string in addition to a formula.  The string has to look like, e.g., "Journal ~ .", so the only real simplification here would be that the `as.formula` wrapper isn't needed.

Comment: I've updated my code accordingly. Thanks for your comment.